# does tf.data.Dataset .from_tensor_slices() preserve the order of examples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

If I have a set of tfrecords, using [.from_tensor_slices()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave) here, will `dataset` created preserve the order of the data? For example, if I have 3 tfrecords (the first one contains 40 examples, the second one contains 30 examples, the third one contains 70 examples) called `1.tfrecord`, `2.tfrecord`, `3.tfrecord` respectively, then I construct `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(['1.tfrecord', '2.tfrecord', '3.tfrecord'])`. During loading, will the order of these examples preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, yes, the order of examples is preserved when using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` with `tfrecord`. Here is a simple example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.io.TFRecordWriter("sample1.tfrecord") as w:
    w.write(b"Record A")
    w.write(b"Record B")

with tf.io.TFRecordWriter("sample2.tfrecord") as w:
    w.write(b"Record C")
    w.write(b"Record D")
    w.write(b"Record E")
    w.write(b"Record F")

with tf.io.TFRecordWriter("sample3.tfrecord") as w:
    w.write(b"Record G")
    w.write(b"Record H")
    w.write(b"Record I")
    w.write(b"Record J")
    w.write(b"Record K")
    w.write(b"Record L")

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["sample1.tfrecord",
                                              "sample2.tfrecord",
                                              "sample3.tfrecord"])
for record in dataset:
   for item in tf.data.TFRecordDataset(record):
     tf.print('Record:', record, 'Item -->', item)
```

```
Record: "sample1.tfrecord" Item --> "Record A"
Record: "sample1.tfrecord" Item --> "Record B"
Record: "sample2.tfrecord" Item --> "Record C"
Record: "sample2.tfrecord" Item --> "Record D"
Record: "sample2.tfrecord" Item --> "Record E"
Record: "sample2.tfrecord" Item --> "Record F"
Record: "sample3.tfrecord" Item --> "Record G"
Record: "sample3.tfrecord" Item --> "Record H"
Record: "sample3.tfrecord" Item --> "Record I"
Record: "sample3.tfrecord" Item --> "Record J"
Record: "sample3.tfrecord" Item --> "Record K"
Record: "sample3.tfrecord" Item --> "Record L"
```

Or:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["sample1.tfrecord",
                                              "sample2.tfrecord",
                                              "sample3.tfrecord"])
for item in tf.data.TFRecordDataset(dataset):
  tf.print('Item -->', item)
```

```
Item --> "Record A"
Item --> "Record B"
Item --> "Record C"
Item --> "Record D"
Item --> "Record E"
Item --> "Record F"
Item --> "Record G"
Item --> "Record H"
Item --> "Record I"
Item --> "Record J"
Item --> "Record K"
Item --> "Record L"
```